# Стек активити в андроид приложении

Tags: android, java

Имеем первое активити, с него переходим на 2-ю, на втором есть кнопочка *Вернуться* и есть аппаратная кнопочка *Back*. Если я перехожу на 2-ю активити, а дальше возвращаюсь назад одним из 2-х вариантов, все хорошо - я опять оказываюсь на первой активити, но если я нажимаю на *Back*, то меня перекидывает опять на это активити, т.е. в стеке хранится еще 1 копия. Вопрос, как правильно организовать эти переходы?

```
public void cancelAction(View v) 
{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
    startActivity(intent); 
    finish(); 
}
```

Comment: а какой код у кнопки возврата? случайно не создаете через intent новую активити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохой у Вас код для возврата назад. Вы просто создаете новую активити, которую кладете в стек. То есть, если Вы так будете открывать-закрывать активити, то в стеке будет целая куча  MainActivity. Именно по этой причине и не работает кнопка "Back".
Что же делать? а не нужно создавать новую активити, просто вызывайте finish();

Comment: спасибо, чет не подумал сразу